# Unable to read team channel messages using microsoft grap API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am able to read channel messages as long as I am a member of a particular channel but I am unable to read channel messages in which I am not a member but I am a global administrator with following delegated permissions.Can anybody help?

`ChannelMessage.Read.All, Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All`

When I am trying to execute I am getting the following response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-10T04:37:36",
      "request-id": "727d898d-ee3e-484d-b2b6-46582834ca9c",
      "client-request-id": "727d898d-ee3e-484d-b2b6-46582834ca9c"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to express that if you are not a member of a particular channel, you cannot read the message of that channel?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-13) rather than [Delegated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-13) permissions for this. When you're using Delegated permissions, you can only access Channels you are a member of (i.e. the same Channels you see in the Teams app).

Note that these are [Protected APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis), so you'll need to request access before you can use them (above and beyond the normal Admin Consent flow).

Comment: Thank You for the explanation I will try with the application permissions after receiving access to the protected API's